# Какой из шаблонов проектирования способен эмулировать макросы?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, макросы, метапрограммирование

С помощью какого из шаблонов проектирования возможно поведение функциональности подобной макросам? В тегах указал Java, но это касается любого статически типизированного языка программирования в котором нет поддержки макросов.

Comment: что такое `эмулировать макросы`? И почему шаблон проектирования должен делатть что т подобное?

Comment: Что такое макросы в вашем понимании?

Comment: @AzizUmarov всмысле в понимании? вот же https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Макрокоманда#Макросы_в_программировании

Comment: @tym32167 потому что нужда в паттернах появляется тогда, когда люди выбирают для своего проекта язык программирования с недостаточным уровнем абстракции.

Comment: нужда в патернах появляется тогда, когда надо решить конкретную проблему. Когда у вас нет проблемы, а есть абстрактный вопрос, то паттерны тут не помогут никак.

Comment: Макросы, о которых вы пишете, относятся к пре-процессингу кода перед компилированием. Ближайшая альтернатива этому будет AOP или кодогенерация. Если же вам надо моделировать бизнес язык (или доменный язык) то я бы поглядел в сторону парсеров/интерпретаторов типа Antlr. Но вообще без деталей вашей задачи/проблемы тут особо не очем говорить.

Comment: Поддержка макросов (ака текстового препроцессора) добавляется в Java (и другие языки) тривиально.